# convert complex json to the Datatable in c#

Tags: c#

How can i convert the  following json to a datatable in C#?

```
{
    "data": {
        "utime": "2020-07-22 16:02:39.628",
        "record": [
            {
                "samt": 0.0,
                "itms": [
                    {
                        "num": 1.0,
                        "itm_det": {
                            "samt": 0.0,
                            "csamt": 0.5,
                            "rt": 18.0,
                            "txval": 15000.0,
                            "camt": 0.0,
                            "iamt": 2700.0
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "val": 20000.01,
                "txval": 15000.0,
                "camt": 0.0,
                "inum": "Manjusha-GSTR1",
                "iamt": 2700.0,
                "csamt": 0.5,
                "inv_typ": "R",
                "pos": "12",
                "idt": "16-07-2017",
                "rchrg": "N",
                "chksum": "23bd7b0296c66900d9b89a7af16facf08bd68a9aa7e0ddb7c7f9aa8d5dd1431e",
                "ctin": "27GSPMH0781G1ZK",
                "cfs": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "ttl_record": 8,
        "fp": "062018",
        "gstin": "33AIYPV3847J1ZC"
    },
    "meta": {
        "form": "6a",
        "level": "L2",
        "fp": "062018",
        "section": "b2b",
        "gstin": "33AIYPV3847J1ZC",
        "flush": "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jagruti, do you have any code you can post? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/), an open source library to convert your JSON to DataTable as below

```
var dt = ChoJSONReader.LoadText("*** YOUR JSON TEXT ***").AsDataTable();
Console.WriteLine(dt.Dump());
```